# How to send "Like my page" invites to other Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-like

I know how to send a "like my page" to my friends, but how could I send "like my page" invites to other Facebook pages that I have already "liked"?

Comment: I heard it is possible now to send invites to other pages too, but I have no clue about it.